# Set derived class field by converting base class pointer

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

```
class A
{
public: 
    int a;
};
class B:public A
{
public:
    int b;
    void foo()
    {
        b=a*a;
    }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ 
    A * a=new A;
    a->a=10;
    ((B*)a)->foo();
    cout<<((B*)a)->b;
}
```

It's working for `b=100`, but I dont know by which rules it works. Where is  `b` stored? I just don't know how its called to google it.

Comment: It's called "don't do that" ;)

Comment: It shows how lucky you are. if you were a ordinary people, its behavior would be undefined.

Comment: @Emadpres: How did you conclude that the OP's behaviour *wasn't* undefined?

Comment: Outside of your question with your given code sample you have a major bug and memory leak in your program. You call new on A, but no one ever releases that memory by calling delete on A when you no longer need it.

Comment: @Emadpres: I would says OP is **un**lucky as it seems to works and so bug is hidden :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, what is happening here is undefined behaviour. It doesn't have a special name; most likely it is called a *programming mistake*. The memory layout of your class `A` is:

```
int a;
```

The memory layout of `B` is:

```
int a;
int b;
```

So in your case, you only allocate space for `a` but you are lucky that the space immediately after it is free (so that no other information is overwritten) and that it doesn't border on unallocated space (otherwise, a fault might occur when trying to write to an unallocated page). So `b` is stored in free space.

In short: **don't rely on this code to work!**

Comment: Note that @sergej 's answer contains quote from the standard that confirms that this is really declared to be undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

The behaviour is undefined. You can only cast `a` to `B*` if it **is** a pointer to a `B`.

Don't do this.

You couldn't even write `A* a = new B;` followed by `(dynamic_cast<B*>(a))->foo();` since the classes are not polymorphic types.

Comment: `*a` will *always* "be an `A`", since `a` is a pointer-to-`A`. The question is whether it will be a most-derived object.

Comment: He couldn't write with `dynamic_cast`, but he could write using `static_cast`, which would work fine provided `a` was initialized by `new B`.

Answer (score 2):

@anderas has provided a very good explanation why the behavior is undefined.

Here is a relevant clause from the standard (n4431, emphasis mine):

> 11 ...
>
> If the rvalue of type “pointer to cv1 B” points to a B that is actually a sub-object of an object of type D, the resulting pointer points to the enclosing object of type D. **Otherwise, the result of the cast is undefined**.
>
> [expr.static.cast]

So, the cast in your code is undefined.

The following would work:

```
class A
{
public: 
    int a;
    virtual void foo() = 0; // make it polymorphic
};
class B:public A
{
public:
    int b;
    virtual void foo()
    {
        b=a*a;
    }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ 
    A * a=new B;  // create an instance of B
    a->a=10;
    ((B*)a)->foo();
    cout<<((B*)a)->b;

    // don't forget to delete 'a'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will lead to 2 undefined behaviour:

1. When you cast your instance of `A` as a `B`.
2. When you use the member variable `b` (this variable does not exist
   in memory).

Here is pontential implementation to use an instance of B as a pointer of A.

```
class A
{
public:
    void setA(int aToSet)
    {
       a = aToSet;
    }
    virtual void foo() = 0;
    virtual void getResult() const = 0;
private:
    int a;
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void foo() override
    {
        b = a * a;
    }
    void getResult() const override
    {
        return b;
    }
private:
    int b;
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{ 
    A *a = new B();
    a->setA(10);
    a->foo();
    cout << a->getResult();
}
```